# Ajax pass value to other php file and use the value in if statement

Tags: php, ajax

```
<td id='account_type'>Asset</td>
```

then ajax

```
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: '__popup-window_ajax.php',
data: { 'AccountType' : $('#account_type').text() },
});
```

then php

```
print_r($_POST['AccountType']);
```

see word `Asset` exactly as here `<td id='account_type'>Asset</td>`

**but**

```
if (($_POST['AccountType']) == 'Asset') {
echo 'Yes, Asset';
}
```

echo nothing

What is wrong?

For example tried

```
$account_type = 'Asset';
if ( $account_type == 'Asset' ) {
echo 'Yes, Asset';
}
```

and works... Does ajax changes values somehow?

**Solution**
Thanks to @Ankit Pokhrel. My **stupid negligence**. After word `Asset` there was blank space. `trim` helped.

Comment: try assigning the value to a variable and compare with the constant string. like this `$val=$_POST['AccountType']; if ($val == 'Asset') {
echo 'Yes'.$val;
}`

Comment: Tried. The same. But this `$account_type = 'Asset'; if ( $account_type == 'Asset' ) {echo 'Yes, Asset';`} works... can not understand

Comment: Thats because $_POST[] returns an array and your trying to compare it with a  single string constant.

Comment: test my solution and write your feedback

Comment: trim the value before comparing. `if( trim($_POST['AccountType']) == 'Asset' ) { echo "Asset"; }`

Comment: Seems it is not array. This `echo $_POST['AccountType'];` works. And tried `print_r ($_POST['AccountType'][0]);` and see `A`

Comment: can you `var_dump($_POST['Asset'])` and post it

Comment: `trim` helped. My stupid negligence. Blank space after word `Asset`

Comment: just to be a smart ass, answer was given 5 mins before Ankit ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can only be a whitespace issue. It has nothing to do with the treatment of `$_POST` or whether or not your data property names are encased in quotes. Trim the value on either side of the transaction.

JS:

```
data: {AccountType: $('#account_type').text().replace(/^\s|\s$/g, '')},
```

PHP

```
trim($_POST['AccountType'])
```

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
if (isset($_POST['AccountType']) && stristr($_POST['AccountType'],'Asset')){   
    //extra content is sent within AccountType variable, check your output sourcecode. 
}

// or

if (isset($_POST['AccountType']) && trim($_POST['AccountType']) =='Asset'){    
//you've got whitespaces in AccountType variable 
}
```